# How to reset artisan of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

this is the package i'm going to install but then i missed a step of populate the table before generate the config

https://github.com/Torann/laravel-currency

end up all the command i typed returning me the following line

```
{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'abc.currency' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `currency`) (Bindings: array (\n))","file":"\/Users\/Me\/Development\/RoomQuickly\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php","line":556}}
```

I did dump-autoload or even composer update but still couldn't get rid of it. any idea?
Thanks

Comment: What is this 'populate the table'? You can populate any table after publishing the config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute:

```
php artisan migrate --package=torann/currency
```

It should create the tables for you.

This step was missing from the Readme I've just sent a pull request to add it.

Comment: yea! i removed the link of requires, then composer update, composer dump-autoload, then add it back, dump-autoload again, and execute this, then fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the artisan tool.

Delete all files and tables of the package, then try again.